# Is it normal that I don't see the webpart I just added?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am creating a page and I don't see the new webpart I just added. When I do gulp serve, I can add the app, and after adding it I see it in the "Apps you can add" section, but when I try to edit a page I just created I don't see it.

Comment: Have you deployed the web part to an app catalog? Depending on how you set it up you might have to add it to the site as an app first. You should then see it listed alongside the lists and libraries under 'Site Contents'

Comment: I had to wait 45 min before being able to add it for some reason. I thought it would be available as soon as I saw the webpart inside the "Apps you can add" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method of development, is to generate the solution package of the webpart component and to deploy it in the application catalog of the site.

Enter the following command to package your client-side solution that contains the web part:

```
gulp package-solution
```

The command creates the package in the sharepoint/solution folder. It's this package that needs to be deployed in the application catalogue. This [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page) in the official Microsoft documentation explains the steps to follow.

Once the webpart component has been deployed on the site, simply run the following command to launch the server and be able to use the webpart in the site :

```
gulp serve --nobrowser
```

Any modification made afterwards in the code will be automatically taken care of by the component. This is a more efficient way of coding.